# How to publish dictionary in Kafka?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka

I am trying to publish a response in a kafka topic. This response is fetched from a mongodb.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
import json
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import sys
import datetime

try:
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://A.B.C.D:27017/prod-production')
    db = client["prod-production"]
except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred while connecting to DB")
    print(e)
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
producer = KafkaProducer(retries=5)
print("Initial time:")
print(datetime.datetime.now())
count = 1
for response in db.Response.find():
    if count >= 20:
        producer.flush()
        sys.exit()
    count += 1
    print(count)
    producer.send('example-topic', bytes(response))
print("Final time")
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "producer.py", line 28, in <module>
    producer.send('collect-production-response', bytes(response)) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

However, in python2, this error does not occur.

Comment: 1) use `json.dumps` instead of `bytes` 2) I might suggest looking into the Debezium or Kafka Connect projects for getting Mongo into Kafka

Comment: Python 2 treats "str" and "bytes" as the same thing - but "unicode" as different object. Python 3 treads "str" and "unicode" as the same thing - but "bytes" as different object.

Comment: @cricket_007 Please post an answer which is your comment, as of now in order for me to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with this problem and I solved it with the two following method.

```
1- producer.send('example-topic', bytes(str(response), 'utf-8'))
```

or

```
2- producer.send('example-topic', str(response))
```