# Converting dataframe in python to json in the below format

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-kafka

I'm looking for a Python code implementation to convert Pandas Dataframe to `json` file in the format mentioned below.

Input Python Dataframe looks like this (`input_data - dataframe name`)

```
  stateacttraf |stateno  | statename | actno | actname | traffic | reward   | id     |   message  

  stateacttraf |     1   |   S1      | 1     | A1      |  22     |   3      | 234569 |   stateactsplit   
  stateacttraf |     1   |   S1      | 2     | A2      |  30     |   4      | 234569 |   stateactsplit  
  stateacttraf |     1   |   S1      | 3     | A3      |  48     |   2.3    | 234569 |   stateactsplit  
  stateacttraf |     2   |   S2      | 1     | A1      |  13     |   4.1    | 234569 |   stateactsplit  
  stateacttraf |     2   |   S2      | 2     | A2      |  27     |   8.2    | 234569 |   stateactsplit  
  stateacttraf |     2   |   S2      | 3     | A3      |  60     |   5.6    | 234569 |   stateactsplit
```

The Dataframe should look like the following sample in json format, that needs to be published in *kafka*:

#### Sample expected json output:

```
{  
"stateacttraf": "1, S1, 1 , A1 , 24.5,3 \n  
 1, S1, 2 , A2 , 25.5,4 \n  
 1, S1, 3 , A3 , 20,2.3 \n  
 2, S2, 1 , A1 , 10,4.1 \n  
 2, S2, 2 , A2 , 10,8.2 \n   
 2, S2, 2 , A2 , 10,5.6 \n",   
 "message": "stateactsplit",  
 "id": 234569  
}
```

In the sample output `\n` just signifies that every row of these `(1, S1, 2 , A2 , 25.5,4)` should be printed in a new line.

Tried to use `input_data.to_json(orient='index', lines=True)`, but the column names keep repeating for every value in every line.

Comment: That's not a good `json` format.  [Working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: @Trenton_M Unfortunately thats the requirement that I have received for the implementation in that format.

Comment: That's truly unfortunate, but it looks like someone provided a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good JSON format, however I have written the code that is right for you:

```
raw_data = {'stateacttraf': ['stateacttraf','stateacttraf','stateacttraf','stateacttraf', 'stateacttraf2','stateacttraf2' ],
        'stateno':     [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'statename':    ['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2','S3', 'S4'], 
        'id':    [234569, 234569, 234569, 234569, 99, 99],
        'message':    ['stateactsplit','stateactsplit', 'stateactsplit','stateactsplit','stateacttraf2', 'stateacttraf2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data).set_index(['stateacttraf'])

               stateno statename      id        message
stateacttraf                                           
stateacttraf         1        S1  234569  stateactsplit
stateacttraf         1        S1  234569  stateactsplit
stateacttraf         1        S1  234569  stateactsplit
stateacttraf         2        S2  234569  stateactsplit
stateacttraf2        3        S3      99  stateacttraf2
stateacttraf2        4        S4      99  stateacttraf2
```

Try this code:

```
index_name = ['stateacttraf', 'message', 'id']
s = df.groupby(index_name).apply(lambda row: '\n '.join(map(lambda x: str(x.tolist())[1:-1], row.values)))
formatted_data = [{index_name[0]:s[i0].values[0], index_name[1]:i1, index_name[2]:i2} for i0, i1, i2 in s.index]
```

and here is the data in your (bad) JSON format:

```
[{'stateacttraf': "1, 'S1', 234569, 'stateactsplit'\n 1, 'S1', 234569, 'stateactsplit'\n 1, 'S1', 234569, 'stateactsplit'\n 2, 'S2', 234569, 'stateactsplit'",
  'message': 'stateactsplit',
  'id': 234569},
 {'stateacttraf': "3, 'S3', 99, 'stateacttraf2'\n 4, 'S4', 99, 'stateacttraf2'",
  'message': 'stateacttraf2',
  'id': 99}]
```

**TIP**: If you don't want to go crazy, I suggest you switch to a standard json format

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I just have 2 questions on this:
1) \n -> Implies that this is for newline character when reading from this file by kafka and not string character right?
2) The formatted_data is technically a list, so if i have to convert to json to publish over kafka; then this would work right `my_json_string = json.dumps(formatted_data)`. Or the list(i.e. formatted_data) itself when published over kafka would suffice ?

Comment: I wish I could, would been so much simpler but thats the requirement I have received without any room for deviation.

Comment: 1) it should be as you say. 2) `json.dumps (formatted_data)` transforms the dictionary into a string, formatted according to the standard json rules. Since a python dictionary is `formatted_data`, `str(formatted_data)` may also suffice. I've never used kafka intensively. Try and let me know :-). If my comment was helpful to you please accept and voteup my answer. Thanks

Comment: As I told you, `str(formatted_data)` should be corrected, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565380/how-to-publish-dictionary-in-kafka

Comment: perfect, then consider accepting my answer, thanks @Datta